# angular2-jwt and Ahead-of-Time Compilation

Tags: angular, auth0, angular2-aot, angular2-jwt

Everything just works fine in JiT compilcation but I get the following compilation error when I try to compile with AoT. Can anyone explain what is going on?

I´m using auth0-lock v.10.4.0  and angular2-jwt v.0.1.24

Error:

```
Module '".../node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt"' has no exported member 'AUTH_PROVIDERS'.
```

I´m using lazy loading so I have a shared module for the AuthService and AUTH_PROVIDER like so:

```
import { AuthService } from '../common/auth.service';
import { AUTH_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2-jwt';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [],
    exports: []
})
export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [
                AuthService,
                AUTH_PROVIDERS]
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution here
https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/158

Instead of AUTH_PROVIDER create your own provider like so:

```
export function authFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    // Config options if you want
  }), http, options);
};

// Include this in your ngModule providers
export const authProvider = {
  provide: AuthHttp,
  deps: [Http, RequestOptions],
  useFactory: authFactory
};
```